# Liquidity Pool Deposit Operation Min/Max Price?

Tags: stellar-core, protocol

Does anyone know what the Min/Max Price parameters on the Liquidity Pool Deposit operation do at a conceptual level?

https://developers.stellar.org/docs/start/list-of-operations/#liquidity-pool-deposit

https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/commit/0cb6260a18050edaa95a4fd2b1dd8de814c0c168

Answer (score 0):

The min/max price will but the current market price of the non-native (XLM) asset.  Example, USDC vs. XLM would be roughly right now 2.91 min  2.93 max if using "Number".  I'm sure they do this for market slippage error so that if the markets are moving fast there is some wiggle room to get you into the AMM vs. exact ratios and the transaction failing.